# c# how to count amount of data received in data receive handler?

Tags: c#

I am receiving data (in byte) from serial port, and now I want to write a if else in the data receive handler.

```
If(condition)
 {}
else
 {}
```

condition for if is: number of bytes received / 8 = interger.
For example, I received 16 bytes of data, so 16/2=8, is an integer. I received 20 bytes of data, 20/8=2.5, it s not an integer.

```
 private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] b = new byte[800];
        int Received;
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        if (condition)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("      Transmission error!");
        }
        else
        {
            Received = sp.Read(b,0,8);
        if (Received < 8) 
            return;
        float f11 = BitConverter.ToSingle(b, 0);
        float f22 = BitConverter.ToSingle(b, 4);
        Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
          textBox3.Text += f11.ToString() + "    "+f22.ToString()+"\r\n";
          //MessageBox.Show("      New Message Received!");
        }));
        Received = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should post code about HOW you read data from serial port. I guess this is the real question.

Comment: yeah okay, alr post!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`% operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx):

```
if (number_of_bytes_received % 8 == 0)
```

Comment: `long` or other [integral types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w.aspx) would work as well, but `int` would be the default choice.